# Changing Memory Values in C++

Tags: c++

I'm relatively new to coding with C++ and have been asked to create a program dealing with pointers and addresses. The part I am getting stuck on is using differences between two memory addresses to change the value of the numerator (we're dealing with fractions).

This is the assignment I was given: http://cdn.frugalfinders.com/assignment.pdf

I'm getting stuck on question 2. Here is the C++ code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include "fraction.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i1;
    fraction f1(2,5);
    int i2;
    fraction farray[5];
    float x1;
    double x2;
    char c1;
    int A[6];
    int *ip1;
    float *fp1;
    fraction *ffp1;
    double *dp1;

    // Print the addresses of the variables
    cout << endl;
    cout << "i1 at:       " << &i1 << endl;
    cout << "f1 at:       " << &f1 << endl;
    cout << "i2 at:       " << &i2 << endl;
    cout << "farray at:   " << &farray << endl;
    cout << "x1 at:       " << &x1 << endl;
    cout << "x2 at:       " << &x2 << endl;
    cout << "c1 at:       " << &c1 << endl;
    cout << "A at:        " << &A << endl;
    cout << "ip1 at:      " << &ip1 << endl;
    cout << "fp1 at:      " << &fp1 << endl;
    cout << "ffp1 at:     " << &ffp1 << endl;
    cout << "dp1 at:      " << &dp1 << endl;

    // Print the values of the variables
    cout << endl;
    cout << "f1 is:       " << f1 << endl;
    cout << "ip1 is:      " << ip1 << endl;
    cout << "fp1 is:      " << fp1 << endl;
    cout << "ffp1 is:     " << ffp1 << endl;
    cout << "dp1 is:      " << dp1 << endl << endl;

    // Store the address of i2 in ip1
    ip1 = &i2;

    // Change the numerator of f1 to 23
    cout << f1 << endl;
    i1 = (&i2) - 4;
    *i1 = 23;
    cout << f1 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I just cannot figure out how to get the part under

```
// Change the numerator of f1 to 23
```

to work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Using 
the difference between the addresses of i2 and f1" - Even doing that subtraction is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I think the title of the question does not really reflect the question. I'd say what you have to do is not change anything in memory, but f1 = fraction() using the new numerator and the old denominator.

Comment: @Pier no it really is that bad read the linked exercise.

Comment: Has that prof ever *read* any part of any of the standards? Because that question is utter nonsense.

Comment: @john you are right... it is bad.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! It makes me feel a lot better that his question is nonsense. I am going to do it the way @john suggested.

Comment: @MitchellWischmann I disagree, but maybe I'm wrong... see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess (it's literally impossible to say for sure) that you might get the output you are expecting with this

```
*(ip1 - 2) = 23;
```

But really this exercise is garbage. Your professor is asking you to write code which is flat out illegal in C++, and which serves no useful purpose I can see.

To explain why a little, you can use *pointer arithmetic* to get new addresses from existing addresses. But pointer arithmetic is only legal in certain situations and it is not legal to use pointer arithmetic to get the address of one variable from the address of another. But that is what you are being asked to do.

Comment: I'm guessing that the professor means the value of the numbers in the addresses, and not the number of the addresses.

Comment: You should calculate the difference, not assume it. Then the question is not that crap, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Since the computer memory is contiguous, so when you are allocating spaces to variables, they are stored one after the other. 
As i2 is declared immediately after f1, the difference between addresses of f1 and i2 will give you the memory space allocated to f1. However, I do not understand how you can possibly use the difference to change the value of the numerator since the difference will give the SPACE occupied by f1 not the address of the numerator.

Comment: There's is no guarantee in C++ that what you say is true. It might be true for some platforms, but absolutely no guarantees at all.

Comment: oh  yes.. thankyou. In that case, It is quite impossible to solve this question.